# Kali Linux Fresh Install Failure

Tags: kali-linux, usb

I'm trying to install Kali linux for the first time. I am installing the newest version on the downloads page and have successfully created a USB boot media using the tool recommended by Kali.

I have checked my bios and have booted the installer. I have tried live mode, and my Asus Laptop freezes on the desktop with no reponse from a keyboard or mouse.

I also tried Graphical install on advanced settings. This time it freezes on checking bootable device media page after selecting location.

Tried this for the past 3 days, can anyone help me?

I also have Windows 10 on the same hard drive, but I created a 20gb non partitioned spot for all the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to give 40gb or 50gb for the latest `2020.1` version and don't select unnecessary tools while installing.